# php unexpect result when using reference

Tags: php

Just see the code ~

```
<?php
$foo = [ 'foo' => 1 ];

$nothing = &$foo['foo'];

$bar = $foo;
$bar['foo'] = '2';

echo $foo['foo'];
```

Every version of php get result `2` but why ?

Isn't `bar` a totally different variable besides `foo` ?

Comment: it is really a duplicated question, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't know what you are looking for it is a really difficult duplicate to find yourself.